# side effects must eventually become externally visible (Write-to-store)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, standards

I seem to recall that in pre-C++11 standardization (probably still there though), there was a wording that mentioned something in the line of

> writes should eventually be "released to memory"

Which is interesting by its vagueness, but also means that careless non-memfence/non-mutex programming still has a chance to work, with code that is multi threaded but yet (rarely) checks for some shared data.

So my question is **what was/is the exact wording** ?

Comment: Something tells me this question is unclear

Comment: You quoted the **exact wording**. didn't you?

Comment: Pre C++11 there were no threads.

Comment: @Detonar no it's a mere recollection, I reconstructed the wording from my remembrance.

Comment: @RichardCritten, it doesn't have to relate to threading, side effects are a valid concern for single threaded code as well since "visible" is of value for DMA. (think how volatile is relevant for the same reason)